# Maven : Not able to download dependencies jta:1.0.1B

Tags: java, maven-2, jta

I'm receiving following error when I run `mvn clean install`.

Error says not able to resolve dependencies `javax.transaction:jta:jar:1.0.1B`

Please note that I'm not refering to `javax.transaction:jta:jar:1.0.1B` in my pom. May be this dependency is refered by some other dependency that I mentioned in my pom.

**Please find the error below**

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building sample-webapp Maven Webapp 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/javax/transaction/jta/1.0.1B/jta-1.0.1B.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 5.810 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-12-05T08:43:47+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 12M/309M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project sample-webapp: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.ganesh:sample-webapp:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact ja
vax.transaction:jta:jar:1.0.1B in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2), try downloading from http://java.sun.com/products/jta -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> that's a legacy library that is not available from Maven Central.
>   It isn't available because there are still some old Sun-era Javax JARS that are not covered under open source licenses.  If you need to access this JTA 1.0.1B library, you will need to replace that dependency using an exclusion.

**note:** and when I hit this url *https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/javax/transaction/jta/1.0.1B/jta-1.0.1B.jar* in the browser, it return to **404 Not Found** then I dont know why you can dowload it.

---

for more info [Why can't I download the javax.transaction:jta:1.0.1B JAR?](http://central.sonatype.org/articles/2012/Mar/22/why-cant-i-download-the-javaxtransactionjta101b-jar/)

Comment: sorry for the wrong information in the question. Yeah I'm not able to download the jar. BTW, because I'm not refereing to this jar directly,is there any command in maven to check which dependency is refering 'jta-1.0.1B.jar`.

Comment: @Ganesh P  mvn dependency:tree It shows transitive dependencies as well.

Comment: New link for more info: https://central.sonatype.org/faq/cannot-download-javax-transaction/